# What permissions are required in Office 365 to move a mail item to another folder?

Tags: vba, move, mailitem, exchange-online

Before migrating to Microsoft 365 I had no issues moving a mail item, using VBA, from a personal inbox to a public folder.

With the change, the following movement of mail items work:

- Shared Mailbox >> Shared Folder
- Shared Mailbox >> Public Folder
- Shared Mailbox >> Private Folder

But these do not:

- Private >> Shared Folder
- Private >> Public Folder

The error I get is:

> Run-time -2147221211 (80040125)  Changes made to the item were lost
> due to a reconnect with the server

This certainly seems like a permission issue.  Anyone know what security policy governs moving a mail item from a personal mailbox folder to another public folder or shared mailbox folder?

The move fails regardless of how the current mail item is accessed:

`Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(I)`

or

```
Set RecipientA = objectNS.CreateRecipient("me@mydomain.com")
Set RecipientA_Items = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(RecipientA, olFolderInbox).Items
Set Item = RecipientA_Items(1)
```

Here is the test code:

```
Set RecipientA = objectNS.CreateRecipient("me@mydomain.com")
Set MyInbox = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(RecipientA, olFolderInbox)
Item.Move MyInbox.Folders("Test")  'This Works (subfolder in my mailbox)

Set PublicRoot = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders)
Set PubCorrespFolder = PublicRoot.Folders("MyCompany").Folders("Processed").Folders("PCorrespondence")
Item.Move PubCorrespFolder ' This Fails (Public Folder)

Set RecipientB = objectNS.CreateRecipient("someonesle@mydomain.com")
Dim SharedInbox As Outlook.folder
Set SharedInbox = objectNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(RecipientB, olFolderInbox)
Item.Move SharedInbox 'This fails (shared mailbox)`
```

Comment: Any help here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114600/cannot-move-private-items-in-shared-mailbox-issue